# Forwarding GNU Screen notification to Ubuntu desktop

Tags: gnu-screen

GNU Screen has utility of monitoring window activity. Is it possible to forward the notification of GNU Screen to Ubuntu desktop environment? For example, when GNU Screen generates a notification, urgent animation in Unity panel is triggered or sound is played on my host, etc.

Comment: How do the notifications posted by GNU Screen look like? A terminal bell? Is it possible to execute a custom command for each notification?

Comment: Dear @krlmlr, I have searched a lot but I was not able to achieve. This did not work for me: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18465/how-can-i-have-screen-transmit-an-audible-bell-produced-in-a-background-window